# Is there a way to reuse a calculated value in a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Take this formula for example:

`=IF(SUM(D7,G7:H7)-SUM(C7,E7:F7)<0, 0, SUM(D7,G7:H7)-SUM(C7,E7:F7))`

I don't like how I have to specify `SUM(D7,G7:H7)-SUM(C7,E7:F7)` twice.  I'd like to define it once and then reuse it (sort of like a variable).  One way to do this is to calculate the value in another cell and then reuse that cell's reference in the formula, but it just makes the spreadsheet more bloated because then you have to hide columns and whatnot.

Comment: I believe this is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771973/are-there-such-things-as-variables-within-an-excel-formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you either have to store it in another variable or repeate it in the cell.  If its really a problem you could use a user defined function to shorten your formula but I wouldn't suggest it for must cases.

For this function you could use:

`max(SUM(D7,G7:H7)-SUM(C7,E7:F7),0)`

Answer (score 1):

Since 2020 Excel has introduced the LET function. Now you can reuse values like you were in VBA. Simply name your variables, specify the calculations and use them.

LET(variableName, value_or_Calculation, ..., finalCalculation)

on "..." you can repeat the logic of first two parameters to set more variables and intermediate calculations.

Source:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999

Comment: Thank you Daniel!   Been looking for an answer for this for years!       the op's answer encoded in Let language (vs. the 'max' option that happens to work for the specific case), looks like, using 'x'  as the interim variable:

=LET(    x,   SUM(D7,G7:H7)-SUM(C7,E7:F7),   IF( x<0, 0, x)    )